# Is there any 8051 assembly language to C code converter

Tags: c, assembly, 8051

Is there any 8051 assembly language to C code converter...??

please help by providing related links..

Comment: Automatic conversion of assembler to C is probably not going to make the program any more readable, if that's what you're worried about, probably quite the opposite.

Comment: I very much doubt it, since such a tool wouldn't make much sense. The code would end up as obscure, unreadable spaghetti.

Comment: @Mike as Joachim has already mentioned...i just want to understand a code of assembly language...

Comment: Can we please stop with downvoting every decompilation question? It's a difficult, but not an impossible problem.

Comment: Madhav, OK, just FYI what's going to help you understand it more than converting it to C, is learning to read assembly. As Lundin pointed out, the code will probably end up being very hard to read anyway and you still won't know *exactly* what code is executing what instruction.

Comment: @Igor - This is a "where can I find some software"-question, which is off topic here. Google is good for those questions.

Comment: And that's a pity. Google doesn't have explanations or comparisons attached to its search results.

Answer (score 3):

8051 assembler code isn't very difficult to understand [unless it's written very badly and/or uses a lot of "clever tricks"] - there aren't that many instructions, most of them are very straight forward. If you have a fair idea of what the code is supposed to do, then it's quite probable that you can read the code and understand it.

Of course, if the code is not doing something you have a fair understanding of, then it's hard no matter if it's C, Pascal or Assembler. In this case, studying the subject of whatever the device does is your starting point. If it's, say, a mobile phone, then understanding mobile phone technology, how keyboards, radios and such things operate will be key to understanding what the code does. If it's a washing machine controller, then understanding valves, motor controllers, etc will be your key to understanding the code. And so on.

Machine generated C code from assembler, when the original code wasn't written in C in the first place is highly likely to look rather messy - in fact, even manually "direct translation without a lot of understanding" has a tendency to be rather hard to follow - because assembler code is often written in a less organized way than a compiler would produce it, leading to strange code when you try to make it into C code.

Comment: ..on top of which, C compilers for 8051 have to do horrible stuff to try and make the best of the pathetically-small DATA/IDATA RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Such a tool does exist:

http://www.microapl.com/asm2c/sample8051.html

However, it might turn out [somewhat expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1377289/422797).